# How do I make a command that stores user ID using JSON? (discord.py)

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I haven't done any codings, but I will explain more detailed about what I want to do.

1. Create the command example named as "!hi"
2. Once a user typed "!hi", that user's ID will be stored to a json file

Comment: Please include your code, approaches and errors you face. You may also take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as nobody is going to code all of this for you.

Comment: Not one of your questions has been answered because of their poor quality and your lack of research, instead of ignoring the useful comments people leave you should read and understand them, otherwise I doubt you're ever gonna get a question answered.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is a good idea if you've never programmed before, but anyway, imma do my best to explain what the code does...

The first part of this program is the importing part. I imported many modules that will be useful, including **json** and **discord**.

```py
import discord
import discord.ext
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import bot
import discord.ext.commands
import json
import os
```

Afterward, I'm going to add some JSON utility, allowing us to manipulate JSON easily

```py
def loadJsonData(name):
    global config
    if os.path.exists(name+".json"):
        with open("{}.json".format(name), "r") as f:
            config = json.load(f)
    else:
        with open("{}.json".format(name), "w") as f:
            f.write("{\"users\": []}")
            f.close()
        with open("{}.json".format(name), "r") as f:
            config = json.load(f)
```

This will create a file if not existing and it will create a *global variable* named config.

This line will set the prefix to "!":

```py
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
```

And the most important part:

```py
@client.command()
async def hi(ctx):
    print(f"We are trying to save the id: {ctx.author.id} !")
    loadJsonData("database")
    config["users"].append(str(ctx.author.id))
    saveConfig("database")
```

This will create a command named **hi**. When executed, it will print out the author's id. It will then use the json utility functions to log it in a json file.

And this last part: Running the bot with the token:

```py
client.run("enter-your-token-here")
```

The full piece of code:

```py
import discord
import discord.ext
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import bot
import discord.ext.commands
import json
import os

def loadJsonData(name):
    global config
    if os.path.exists(name+".json"):
        with open("{}.json".format(name), "r") as f:
            config = json.load(f)
    else:
        with open("{}.json".format(name), "w") as f:
            f.write("{\"users\": []}")
            f.close()
        with open("{}.json".format(name), "r") as f:
            config = json.load(f)

def saveConfig(name):
    with open("{}.json".format(name), "w") as f:
        json.dump(config, f, indent=4)

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.command()
async def hi(ctx):
    print(f"We are trying to save the id: {ctx.author.id} !")
    loadJsonData("database")
    config["users"].append(str(ctx.author.id))
    saveConfig("database")

client.run("enter-your-token-here")
```

Comment: Please do not spoon feed code to people that haven’t done any research at all

Comment: thanks for the help but I have done them myself in my own way.